# Can I choose to forgo an attack roll when still targeting a creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, spellcasting, targeting

Suppose you use a spell like steel wind strike which allows you to target up to five different creatures and at the end of the spell you are allowed to teleport into 5ft of any of those targets. Now you have either just four targets or you want to end up besides an ally for any given reason.

Would you technically be able to teleport up to him, choose to not attack or miss on purpose and then teleport back to him? Or rather choose him as the last target.

I mean I would allow it, but I am curious on why I could be wrong on this one.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112665/discussion-on-question-by-visitmytent-can-i-choose-to-forgo-an-attack-roll-when).